# Where does faker get the fake data from?

Tags: python, faker

I need to be able to convince my employer and ensure that the data that I generate with `faker` module is never the *personally identifiable information* of some real people.

So, my genuine question is: **where does `faker` get names, email addresses, employers' names etc. from? What is their source for these?** Thank you.

Comment: from the Readme: "Faker generates data at random" (obv.)

Comment: take a look at [this](https://github.com/joke2k/faker/blob/master/faker/providers/person/es_ES/__init__.py).basically each of its providers have a large list of features and it randomly generates different combinations of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More specifically, all the static data is present in their repo: https://github.com/stympy/faker/tree/38f04369bfa11e17cc34f13de3468b6ace371820/lib/locales/en

For example, the `name.yml` contains first, middle, and last names to be used to create new names:

https://github.com/stympy/faker/blob/38f04369bfa11e17cc34f13de3468b6ace371820/lib/locales/en/name.yml

Answer (score 1):

If in doubt you can always look at the [source code](https://github.com/joke2k/faker/blob/master/faker/providers/person/de_DE/__init__.py)!

Basically Faker has Tables of things like first and last names and combines them using a random function. The source of the tables is also listed in the source code. In the example linked above the data comes from Wikipedias lists of common names for the specified region.

The [code](https://github.com/joke2k/faker/blob/master/faker/providers/person/__init__.py) to retrieve the data from the list of entries looks like this:

```
  def name(self):
        """
        :example 'John Doe'
        """
        pattern = self.random_element(self.formats)
        return self.generator.parse(pattern)

    def first_name(self):
        return self.random_element(self.first_names)

    def last_name(self):
return self.random_element(self.last_names)
```